# I am trying to wrap my head around below elasticsearch dsl. Can someone tell me how `must` clause is used below

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
GET qnaindexfinal/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "common":{  
                  "question.questionText":{  
                     "query":"showrroom",
                     "cutoff_frequency":0.001
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "modelId":{  
                     "value":78
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Please help me with the above dsl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With queries in elasticsearch it's best to break things down a little.

`common` [same as a term but for more than one keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html)

`term` value == 78

`must` in this context is checking that the only documents returned match both common and term.

Comment: But the term query is in filter context which is a part of bool query and not the must clause.

Comment: @KumarSwapnil that means both of the subqueries must return true for bool to evaluate to true.